# Customize the import mechanism in Python

Tags: python, python-import

Assume that there is a Python library called `config`:

```
# config.py
import requests
def get(name):
    return requests.get(
        'http://example.com/api/get_config',
        params={'conf_name': name}
    ).json()
```

And I can use it like `import config; FOO=config.get('FOO')`.

I'm wondering is it possible for `config.py` to "patch" the import machanism, in order to simplify its usage, like:

`from config import FOO` (which will call `get('FOO')` and return the value)

Comment: Do you mean that by importing config you have a variable named foo in your mew script?

Comment: Why don't you use `from config import get` and `foo = get('FOO')` in your new script?

Comment: This article might be useful: [Customizing the Python Import System](http://blog.dowski.com/2008/07/31/customizing-the-python-import-system/)

Comment: Also see Python 3's [**import hooks**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#import-hooks)

Comment: Also article [Hacking Python Imports](http://xion.org.pl/2012/05/06/hacking-python-imports/)

Comment: The article is a workaround but it's not perfect, because the import-hook is set AFTER the `from config import ...` statement, thus we have to separate the import statement into 2 parts, like `import config; import foo`

Comment: @elcombato Actually I had a `config.py` containing the hard-coded constants, and I want it to fetch the constants from a server instead of using the hard-coded values, but I don't want to break the old code.

Comment: Do you know the names of the constants in compile time ?